# Read previous and next observations

Tags: sas

I have a dataset like this(sp is an indicator):

```
datetime        sp
ddmmyy:10:30:00 N
ddmmyy:10:31:00 N
ddmmyy:10:32:00 Y
ddmmyy:10:33:00 N
ddmmyy:10:34:00 N
```

And I would like to extract observations with "Y" and also the previous and next one:

```
ID              sp
ddmmyy:10:31:00 N
ddmmyy:10:32:00 Y
ddmmyy:10:33:00 N
```

I tired to use "lag" and successfully extract the observations with "Y" and the next one, but still have no idea about how to extract the  previous one.

Here is my try:

```
data surprise_6_step3; set surprise_6_step2;
length lag_sp $1;
lag_sp=lag(sp);
if sp='N' and lag(sp)='N' then delete;
run;
```

and the result is:

```
ID              sp
ddmmyy:10:32:00 Y
ddmmyy:10:33:00 N
```

Any methods to extract the previous observation also?
Thx for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `point` option in `set` statement in data step.
Like this:

```
data extract;
set surprise_6_step2 nobs=nobs;
if sp = 'Y' then do;
  current = _N_;
  prev = current - 1;
  next = current + 1;

  if prev > 0 then do;
    set x point = prev;
    output;
  end;

  set x point = current;
  output;

  if next <= nobs then do;
    set x point = next;
    output;
  end;
end;

run;
```

There is an implicite loop through dataset when you use it in `set` statement. 
`_N_` is an automatic variable that contains information about what observation is implicite loop on (starts from 1). When you find your value, you store the value of `_N_` into variable `current` so you know on which row you have found it. `nobs` is total number of observations in a dataset.

Checking if `prev` is greater then 0 and if `next` is less then `nobs` avoids an error if your row is first in a dataset (then there is no previous row) and if your row is last in a dataset (then there is no next row).

Comment: Thx, it works. Would u mind explaining further about "current = _N_;" and "if prev > 0 then do;"?

Comment: I expanded my answer a bit. If there is anything you would like further explanation on, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Just a quick one. what does 'x' mean in you code. I have very similar question, but when I copy and paste the code. SAS gives me 'File WORK.x does not exist'.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* generate test data */
data test;
    do dt = 1 to 100;
        sp = ifc( rand("uniform") > 0.75, "Y", "N" );
        output;
    end;
run;

proc sql;
    create table test2 as
        select  *,
            monotonic() as _n
        from  test
    ;
    create table test3 ( drop= _n ) as
        select  a.*
        from    test2 as a
        full join   test2 as b
            on  a._n = b._n + 1
        full join   test2 as c
            on a._n = c._n - 1
        where   a.sp = "Y"
            or b.sp = "Y"
            or c.sp = "Y"
    ;
quit;
```