# SAS: Extract previous and next observations

Tags: sas, window, extract

I have a dataset like this(type is an indicator):

```
 datetime         type
 ...
 ddmmyy:10:30:00  0
 ddmmyy:10:31:00  0
 ddmmyy:10:32:00  1
 ddmmyy:10:33:00  0
 ddmmyy:10:34:00  1
 ddmmyy:10:35:00  0
 ...
```

I was trying to extract data with type 1 and also  the previous and next one.  Just try to extract (-1,+1) window based on type 1.

```
datetime         type
...
ddmmyy:10:31:00  0
ddmmyy:10:32:00  1
ddmmyy:10:33:00  0
ddmmyy:10:34:00  1
ddmmyy:10:35:00  0
...
```

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133827/read-previous-and-next-observations). I copied and pasted the code, but I am not quite sure what does 'x' mean in his code. SAS gives me 'File WORK.x does not exist'.

Can someone help me out? Thx.

Comment: `have` (or `x` in the link) is used in example code as a place holder for your input dataset.  For example if I was to try to give you code for this problem I would have to use that artifice since you have not stated in your question a name for your input dataset.

Answer (score 3):

The X data set  in the other post is the same source table you are filtering, so the logical order of the code is:

1. Check every row in the table 'Have', `_N_` holds the current row number,
2. If Type = 1 then `Set Have Point=_N_` goes to row `_N_` in the 'Have' table and outputs that row to the new table 'want', then continues to the next row. The `_N_` can be the pointer to the current, previous or next row. ( The two IF statements handles the cases of first row and last row; where there is no Previous or no Next)

Full Working Code:

```
data have;
length datetime $23.;
input datetime $ type ;
datalines;
ddmmyy:10:30:00  0
ddmmyy:10:31:00  0
ddmmyy:10:32:00  1
ddmmyy:10:33:00  0
ddmmyy:10:34:00  1
ddmmyy:10:35:00  0
;
run;

data want;
set have nobs=nobs;
if type = 1 then do;
  current = _N_;
  prev = current - 1;
  next = current + 1;

  if prev > 0 then do;
    set have point = prev;
    output;
  end;

  set have point = current;
  output;

  if next <= nobs then do;
    set have point = next;
    output;
  end;
end;
run;

 proc sort data=want noduprecs;
      by _all_ ; Run;
```

Note: I added an extra step `proc sort` to remove duplicate rows.

Output:

```
 datetime=ddmmyy:10:31:00 type=0
 datetime=ddmmyy:10:32:00 type=1
 datetime=ddmmyy:10:33:00 type=0
 datetime=ddmmyy:10:34:00 type=1
 datetime=ddmmyy:10:35:00 type=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Move next observation up and compare two observations at the same row or use lag to compare the current observation and previous observation.

```
data have;
length datetime $23.;
input datetime $ type ;
datalines;
ddmmyy:10:30:00  0
ddmmyy:10:31:00  0
ddmmyy:10:32:00  1
ddmmyy:10:33:00  0
ddmmyy:10:34:00  1
ddmmyy:10:35:00  0
;
run; 

data want;
    merge have have(firstobs=2 keep=type rename=(type=_type));
    if max(type,_type) or max(type,lag(type)) ;
    drop _type;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

For you example data that does not have any id or group variable it should be pretty straight forward. Instead of thinking about moving back and forth in the file, just create new variables that contain the previous (`LAG_TYPE`) and next (`LEAD_TYPE`) value for `TYPE`.  Then your requirement to keep the observations before the one with TYPE=1 is translated to keeping the observations where LEAD_TYPE=1.

Let's convert your sample data into a dataset.

```
data have ;
  input datetime :$15. type ;
cards;
ddmmyy:10:30:00  0
ddmmyy:10:31:00  0
ddmmyy:10:32:00  1
ddmmyy:10:33:00  0
ddmmyy:10:34:00  1
ddmmyy:10:35:00  0
;
```

Rather than actually keeping the required observations I will make a new variable KEEP that will be true for records that meet your criteria.

```
data want ;
  recno+1;
  set have end=eof;
  lag_type=lag(type);
  if not eof then set have(firstobs=2 keep=type rename=(type=lead_type));
  else lead_type=.;
  keep= (type=1 or lag_type=1 or lead_type=1) ;
run;
```

Here is the result.

```
recno       datetime        type    lag_type lead_type    keep
  1      ddmmyy:10:30:00      0         .         0        0
  2      ddmmyy:10:31:00      0         0         1        1
  3      ddmmyy:10:32:00      1         0         0        1
  4      ddmmyy:10:33:00      0         1         1        1
  5      ddmmyy:10:34:00      1         0         0        1
  6      ddmmyy:10:35:00      0         1         .        1
```